# ASP.NET Head Login View Text

Tags: asp.net

For some reason the text (Log In) inside the HeadLoginView in ASP.NET is being displayed as grey not white and only visible when i hover on it, I want it white and always visible.

What am I doing wrong? Also how/where do I code the signout when a user is logged in?

[small screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXsoI.png)

Code:

```
<!-- Cart -->
    <div id="cart">
        <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        <a href="shoppingCart.aspx" class="cart-link">Your Shopping Cart</a>        
    </div>
    <!-- End Cart -->!
```

Comment: I think you have some style defined for `a` tag in your css file and that style is used by loginview control `a` tag also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change font color of hyperlink text via *CSS* attribute.

```
#cart a
{
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some CSS throwing off the styles of the links somewhere.  You can track this down using IE's developer tools or FireBug in FireFox.  You can always style it yourself like @AVD suggested.

Also, with that template and logging out, the LoginStatus generates a logout link and there is code within the LoginStatus control itself to actually perform the logout process.